# How to read a specific line from a text file in c++?

Tags: c++

C++ program that displays on the screen item codes with corresponding
item descriptions and prices. It asks the user to enter the code of the item
purchased by a customer. It looks for a match of the item code stored in items.txt.

How can I output only a specific line from a text file after the user inputs the item code?

Comment: Just use a counter `size_t n = 0;` and read with `std::getline()`. increment the line counter each time `getline()` succeeds until you reach the desired line. Alternatively, you can read the entire file in binary mode into a string and then count `'\n'` characters until you reach the one before the line you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the file line-by-line (`std::getline`), extract (depending on the exact format, e.g. by searching for a whitespace in the string) and compare the code and then return the corresponding line on a match.

It is not possible to access lines from a text file directly by index or content.

This is assuming that you mean the file contains lines in the form

```
code1 item1
code2 item2
//...
```

If the code is just the index of the line, then you only need to call `std::getline` in a loop with a loop counter for the current index of the line.

---

If you do this multiple times on the same file, you should probably parse the whole content first line-by-line into a `std::vector<std::string>` or a `std::(unordered_)map<std::string, std::string>` or something similar to avoid the costly repeated iteration.

Depending on the use case, maybe it would be even better to parse the data into a database first and then query the database, even if it is only e.g. sqlite or something like that.

Comment: Though if it is done multiple times OP may to want to create index file or store data in different format.